# site-Logo appears for me but not for others

Tags: site-logo

I created a logo for my SharePoint Site (Top left) and added it to my SiteAssets folder.

[image]

It appears fine for me but when another user is on the SharePoint Site the image doesn't appear. Why is that?

(how it appears for other users)

[image]

Comment: Is this publishing site n did u published the image?

Answer (score 4):

- Open up Site Assets
- Then Checkin the image file
- Then Publish a Major Version